# Is "vernacular" or "jargon" suitable to describe the special words that a particular group of people use in their industry?

Tags: word-choice, difference

I'm listening to a podcast about American truckers' life. [The first episode](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5d39b277b437ad00019c4c8f/t/5e57f8db046a7c3fb784f52d/1582823657751/Ep1_Transcript_The+Biggest+Tailgate+in+Trucking.pdf) introduces the names that truckers use to call the different trucks. For example:

- "reefer trucks": refrigerator freight trucks
- "skateboards": big flat trailers with loads of lumber and steel
- "parking lots": car haulers
- "tanker yanker": a tanker truck

One trucker in the episode said "I mean, there's all kinds of **terminology** for'em" so I know I can use the word "terminology" to describe these names that probably only truckers use.

But **I'm wondering if the word "vernacular" or "jargon" can be used, too.** **If they can, what's the difference between them?**

I see ["vernacular"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/vernacular) is defined as follows:

> the form of a language that a particular group of speakers use naturally, especially in informal situations

This explanation (along with the other explanations on the same page) doesn't say that "vernacular" is restricted to the people from the same region. It can refer to the language spoken by the people from a particular region, but the dictionary also says it can refer to the language by **a particular group**. In my case, that is the group of the truckers.

I see ["jargon"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/jargon) is defined as follows:

> special words and phrases that are used by particular groups of people, especially in their work.

It looks like "jargon" is a better fit because it seems to be specifically about "particular groups of people" "in their work". All the names I mentioned above are used by truckers when they talk about their work.

In sum, my questions are:

- In addition to "terminology", **can I use "vernacular" or "jargon" to describe the names of the trucks that truckers call them?**
- **What's the difference between "vernacular" and "jargon"?** It seems "vernacular" has a larger scope than "jargon" because "vernacular" can be the language of people from either a region or a group, while "jargon" is more associated with people's profession.

I also looked at these questions:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/q/117627/7342
- https://english.stackexchange.com/q/165511/7342
- https://english.stackexchange.com/q/32390/7342

However, they all mention "vernacular" and "jargon" but none of them seem to compare these two words specifically.

Comment: You are right that _jargon_ is the appropriate word for the private language of people in a a particular occupation.

Comment: If you look carefully at the definition for "vernacular" you'll see it is "the **form** of **a** language". It is more about differences in how a group speaks compared to the "standard" form of a language than just terminology. There is also "vernacular" architecture, for example. This is one example of vernacular English from Huckleberry Finn *What's the use you learning to do right, when it's troublesome to do right and it ain't no trouble to do wrong, and the wages is just the same?*

Comment: As shown by [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28vernacular%29-%28in+the+vernacular%29%2Cin+the+vernacular&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), the word ***vernacular*** very often occurs in the expression ***in the vernacular***. Where it *always* means ***informal, colloquial*** speech. Not at all the same as ***jargon***, which just means the specific usages peculiar to a commercial, academic, or other group (orthogonal to "colloquial", often just meaning "industry-specific terminology" that's meaningless to people not in that business).

Comment: I think the distinction here could be easily be established using online dictionaries.

Comment: @ColleenV: The one bit of "vernacular" I remember from Huck Finn is that he [***lit out for the territory***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22lit+out+for+the+territory%22) I couldn't remember whether the subject there was ***I*** or ***he*** (or ***we***, if it was Huck *and* Tom Sawyer), so I just did that linked Google Books search. But perhaps it wasn't so much "vernacular" as *Mark Twain's **quaint turn of phrase***, given that the vast majority of Google Books matches are ***either from or about*** Huckleberry Finn.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it is mostly because Twain is a good writer that managed to capture the distinctive Southern vernacular without mocking or disparaging it, and it's fairly easy to suss out the meaning of text written in that vernacular. I have heard "lit out" in real speech more than a once, eg "When she heard there was a big sale at Macy's she lit out of here like her hair was on fire." Twain wrote the words without trying to convey the Southern accent for every one of them.

Comment: @ColleenV: Surely if that particular turn of phrase was genuinely typical of the Southern vernacular, it would have occurred in many other texts. The whole point of the second half of my comment was to point out that we ***don't*** see many "non-Twain" references. Which would be somewhat akin to searching for the utterance *"**Leave it out, mate**!"* and discovering that most of the matches are in fact found within scripts from the BBC's *Eastenders* soap opera. I don't claim Twain *invented* the usage, but he certainly *popularised* it (without which it might simply have vanished by now! :)

Comment: (I suggest it's more accurate to say the usage is ***evocative*** of the Southern vernacular, rather than ***typical*** of it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The point is that Twain wrote all of the book in the vernacular, not just the dialog. That's why (in part) his writing is special. Kids learn right quick iffen you want good grades you write it how teach tells you. Typically the Southern vernacular is associated with being ignorant, and few writers want their main characters perceived that way. I'm not surprised that much of accurate Southern vernacular is hard to find in literature. It doesn't mean folks don't talk like that. https://letslearnslang.com/texas-slang-words-sayings/

Comment: @ColleenV: Well, we might perhaps make some inferences from the fact that Mark Twain is right up there with Oscar Wilde and Winston Churchill as "people to whom most memorable turns of phrase are attributed" (which *isn't* an attribute I'd naturally associate with, say, Charles Dickens, even though he had a lot of characters speaking in "the common tongue"). Whatever - I'm sure we both agree that Twain's writings epitomise ***vernacular*** language, not ***jargon***.